# Java- How to manage a database connection in a large java project

Tags: java, database, connection

The main question is that in a a large/big java project with multiple classes having multiple db connection,

Should we use a global Single Connection to db and run it till the program ends and close it at the end of program or
Should we use multiple db connections whenever it is required ?
which is better in terms of security , ease of access.

Comment: Your criteria for evaluation: *security* and *ease of access* are **opposites**. However, in this case, use a [*connection pool*](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) and be done with it.

Comment: thanks @elliott-frisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to hand over connection management to a connection pool like [**Tomcat JDBC Pool.**](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

List of advantages taken from Official doc,

> Features added over other connection pool implementations
>
> 1.Support for highly **concurrent** environments and multi core/cpu systems.
>
> 2.Dynamic implementation of interface, will support java.sql and javax.sql interfaces for your runtime environment (as long as your
>   JDBC driver does the same), even when compiled with a lower version of
>   the JDK.
>
> 3.Validation intervals - we don't have to validate every single time we use the connection, we can do this when we borrow or return the
>   connection, just not more frequent than an interval we can configure.
>
> 4.**Run-Once query**, a configurable query that will be run only once, when the connection to the database is established. Very useful to
>   setup session settings, that you want to exist during the entire time
>   the connection is established.
>
> 5.Ability to configure custom **interceptors**. This allows you to write custom interceptors to enhance the functionality. You can use
>   interceptors to gather query stats, cache session states, reconnect
>   the connection upon failures, retry queries, cache query results, and
>   so on. Your options are endless and the interceptors are dynamic, not
>   tied to a JDK version of a java.sql/javax.sql interface.
>
> 6.**High performance** - we will show some differences in performance later on
>
> 7.Extremely **simple**, due to the very simplified implementation, the line count and source file count are very low, compare with c3p0 that
>   has over 200 source files(last time we checked), Tomcat jdbc has a
>   core of 8 files, the connection pool itself is about half that. As
>   bugs may occur, they will be faster to track down, and easier to fix.
>   Complexity reduction has been a focus from inception.
>
> 8.**Asynchronous** connection retrieval - you can queue your request for a connection and receive a Future back.
>
> 9.Better **idle connection handling**. Instead of closing connections directly, it can still pool connections and sizes the idle pool with a
>   smarter algorithm.
>
> 10.You can decide at what moment **connections are considered abandoned,** is it when the pool is full, or directly at a timeout by specifying a
>   pool usage threshold.
>
> 11.The **abandon connection timer** will reset upon a statement/query activity. Allowing a connections that is in use for a long time to not
>   timeout. This is achieved using the ResetAbandonedTimer
>
> 12.**Close connections** after they have been connected for a certain time. Age based close upon return to the pool.
>
> 13.Get **JMX notifications** and log entries when connections are suspected for being abandoned. This is similar to the
>   removeAbandonedTimeout but it doesn't take any action, only reports
>   the information. This is achieved using the suspectTimeout attribute.
>
> 14.Connections can be retrieved from a java.sql.Driver, javax.sql.DataSource or javax.sql.XADataSource This is achieved using
>   the dataSource and dataSourceJNDI attributes.
>
> 15.XA connection support

**Sample:**

And here is an example on how to configure a **resource for JNDI lookups.**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testOnReturn="false"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
          maxActive="100"
          minIdle="10"
          maxWait="10000"
          initialSize="10"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          logAbandoned="true"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
          jmxEnabled="true"
          jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
            org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
          username="root"
          password="password"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a "big" project I would use an application container to manage the database connections for me.
Security is not only depending on the connection to the database. For me this leads a bit too far. Security can always be an issue if the design has flaws, e.g. SQL Injections.

Answer (score 0):

> Should we use a global Single Connection to db and run it till the
>   program ends and close it at the end of program?

In general, you should never use a single connection for the whole application till the program ends, which is a bad practice.

> Should we use multiple db connections whenever it is required?**

Yes, you need to use multiple connections and release each connection object whenever the task is done i.e., ALWAYS close the resources in `finally` block or use **try-with-resources** such that they don't create any connection leaks.

**Database connection creation is costly** and in an enterprise application, you need to go for **connection pooling** which gets loaded with the specific number of connections during the startup and you will use & return the connections from the pool. You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/connpoca.htm#1057365) more on this.